# cmake: how to find a binary inside of an app bundle on macos?

Tags: macos, cmake

**Current situation**

In order to find the binary `foo` I use the following cmake code:

```
find_program(
    FOO
    NAMES foo
    HINTS /Applications/foo-company/foo-subdir/foo/foo.app
    PATH_SUFFIXES Contents/MacOS/bin
)
```

This works so far but it is rather ugly.

**Desired situation**

I want cmake to actually *search for me* instead of me having to point it's nose directly at it.

**What I tried so far**

It felt like [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) could do the job, but the following code failed to find anything:

- ```
  find_package(
      FOO
      NAMES foo
  )
  ```
- ```
  find_package(
      FOO
      NAMES foo
      HINTS /Applications/foo-company/foo-subdir
  )
  ```
- ```
  find_package(
      FOO
      NAMES foo
      HINTS /Applications/foo-company/foo-subdir/foo
  )
  ```

**Update 1, 2020-07-12 18:00**

- Corrected `find_program` to `find_package` in "What I tried so far".
- I did not explicitly mention it but using `find_package` I hoped to find the app bundle first and then specify the program I need from it.
- `find_package` fails for reasons squareskittles explains: I'd nee a `Find<PackageName>.cmake` or `<PackageName>Config.cmake` file for that.

Comment: If you are trying to use `find_package()` (your code still says `find_program`), your package *must* have a `Find<PackageName>.cmake` or `<PackageName>Config.cmake` file, as stated in the `find_package` documentation.

Comment: @squareskittles oops that was a typo...